# Adding custom function to gmail's web surface to access a WCF web service

Tags: wcf, gmail

I need a way to extend GMail's web surface in order to be able to send the message body of the currently selected emails (multi select) to my WCF .Net web service. Is there a way to accomplish this in a secure way? I need it to be available only by me and other colleges I trust.

Thank you.

-- Hudgi